# How to get the unverifiedEmail value of a user after a change email request?

Tags: craft3, users, query, elementquery

The `currentUser.unverifiedEmail` variable, which is public, is always empty on front end even after email change.

I thought it was a bug. I contacted Craft support about this, and here is Brad's answer:

> That's expected behavior... the default UserQuery (which is what {{
>   currentUser }} is) only grabs a small subset of columns in it's select
>   to avoid exposing potentially sensitive user account information
>   throughout the system.
>   https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/elements/db/UserQuery.php#L310-L325
>
> If you want anything outside of that, you'll have to query for the
>   data directly.

I tried this custom query:
`{{ craft.users.id(currentUser.id).one().unverifiedEmail }}`.
But even after requesting an email change, the value remain empty.

Any idea how to make this query from Twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the value

```
{% set user = craft.users
    .id(currentUser.id)
    .addSelect(['users.unverifiedEmail'])
    .one()
%}
{{ user.unverifiedEmail }}
```